# Skaffold/IntelliJ how to configure maven mirror

Tags: intellij-idea, skaffold

I am experimenting with Skaffold and IntelliJ to develop directly in Kubernetes, but I am having trouble with maven, when IntelliJ try to initialize the environment following erroer occurs in

```
 Running "bash -c curl --fail --show-error --silent --location --retry 3 
 https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.10%2B9/OpenJDK11U- 
 jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.10_9.tar.gz | tar xz --directory /layers/google.java.runtime/java -- 
 strip-components=1"
 [builder] Done "bash -c curl --fail --show-error --silent --location --retry..." (59.3720683s)
 [builder] === Java - Maven (google.java.maven@0.9.0) ===
 [builder] Installing Maven v3.6.3 

 [builder] Running "/layers/google.java.maven/maven/bin/mvn clean package --batch-mode -DskipTests -- 
 quiet"
 [builder] [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
```

The problem is, some of my Spring Boot Application dependencies are defined in our Nexus Repository and that is defined mirror in my maven settings.xml and this process does not know that mirror configuration and I can't find a way to configure that for skaffold.

I try set settings.xml in skaffold.yml as following

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta11
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: myproject/myapp
  jib:
    args:
    -  --settings=C:\maven\conf\settings.xml
  tagPolicy:
  sha256: {}
```

Anybody had any idea how to let 'google.java.maven' to use my mirror configuration?

Thx for answers...

Comment: Your `skaffold.yaml` is at odds with what you're reporting as your transcript shows that Skaffold is trying to use GCP Buildpacks to build.  There are some indentation issues in your yaml too as the `jib:` should be part of the artifact object.  I'll address the different approaches below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skaffold supports three builders work out of the box for Java apps: Jib, Buildpacks, and Docker.  The Jib builder will be easiest for your needs.

Jib builds run on your host machine (vs within a containerized environment).  Because Skaffold's Jib builder just invokes Maven or Gradle directly, they use your account settings with no additional configuration required (specifically your `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` and your artifact cache in `$HOME/.m2/repository`).  Your `skaffold.yaml` above just needs a small indentation tweak and it should all work:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta11
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: myproject/myapp
    jib: {}
  tagPolicy:
    sha256: {}
```

You can see a working example in the [Skaffold examples](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/tree/master/examples/jib).

Docker and Buildpacks builds are run within a container: that is, the source is *copied* into the container.  As a result, you can't reference files outside of the *build context*, like your `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`.  You *could* create a model `settings.xml` within your source directory and reference that file, and then use environment variables or build-arguments to pass in usernames and passwords.  But it becomes quite involved.

We have an open issue to [allow mounting directories as volumes for the Buildpacks builder](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/5407), and we should be able to do the same for the Docker builder.  That functionality would make it easier to support your situation if you really wanted to use Buildpacks or Docker.